# Ajax query issue on live server

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, http-status-code-404

I have Been learning Laravel for the past year and I recently noticed a particularly strange behaviour. Most of my designs are html/css/JS.. and all my assets are loading great, except for a behaviour with the scripts.

When running PHP artisan serve all my scripts load great. I can do GET/POST without any issues. But if I access my app via full path url (I.e : WAMP or XAMP) all the scripts return 404 in the console when I inspect my page.

I even deployed on live servers (I.e GoDaddy) and the same behaviour is present. GET and POST Ajax calls are returning 404.

Anyone has ever encountered this before ?

I clear my routes, cache, updated n’y composer, contacted hosting provider to see if any security could block or tag my script as « bad ». I have been searching for a few days and can’t find any other threads out there.

Comment: This sounds like an incorrectly configured document root. Document root should be configured as the `public` folder. That is where `index.php` kicks off your Laravel application. The [Deployment docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment) will likely help you out. For apache, have a look at the [v7 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation)

Comment: Makes sense, Will let you know in a couple of days.